# Writing time with characters

Tags: time-date

I would like to get the time, then insert the equivalent time using characters inside a
buffer.

Suppose the time is `14:42:17`, I want to have the following

```
H_H_              ; Hours (12 hours)
M_M_M_M_M_M_M_M_  ; Minutes in 5 minute steps
M_M_              ; Minutes on remainder
S_S_S_            ; Seconds in 5 second steps
S_S_              ; Seconds on remainder
```

I have the following three functions to print `"H_"`, `"M_"` and `"S_"`.

```
(defun ticker-hour ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)
  (insert "H_"))
```

and the same for minutes and seconds using the two corresponding functions `ticker-minute` and `ticker-second`.

Have started with taking the current time using `(current-time-string)`.  But I could use `(decode-time)` which seems more convenient.
I get the information with this function.

```
(defun fire-current-time ()
  "TODO."
  (interactive)

  (let ( (ss (nth 0 (decode-time)))    ; seconds
         (mm (nth 1 (decode-time)))    ; minutes
         (hh (nth 2 (decode-time))) )  ; hours

    (message "hh: %d" hh)
    (message "mm: %d" mm)
    (message "ss: %d" ss)))
```

Comment: What have you tried? What specifically have you had trouble with?

Comment: I think I understand what you mean with the minutes and seconds, but how are the hours represented? Why is it that `14` gets translated to `H_H_`? What would '09` hours be translated to? Or `21`?

Comment: Based on 12 hours, 14 hours is 2pm.

Comment: So how do you distinguish AM from PM?

Comment: I switch a magenta light for PM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read chapter 11.5 Iteration of the Emacs Lisp Manual, which you can read inside of Emacs by typing `C-h i`. There you will find documentation about several ways to iterate, or loop. The easiest to use in your case is probably `dotimes`:

```lisp
(dotimes (i 2)
  (ticker-hour))
(insert "\n")
(dotimes (i 8)
  (ticker-minute))
… ; and so on
```

Computing the number of times to execute each loop is left as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: `(terpri)` is not making a newline.

Comment: What did you learn from reading its documentation?

Comment: Looks like the newlines are being introduced in the `*Messages*` buffer.